# Why only get first character of string?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Why I only got the first character and not the whole string in tag?

```
#This for multiple URL
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import itertools

with open('site_test.txt') as site_test:
    sites = (line.strip() for line in site_test)
    for site in sites:
        site = urllib2.urlopen(site)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site, "html.parser")

        for x, y, z, e in itertools.izip(soup.find_all('h1')[0], soup.find_all('p')[1], soup.find_all('p')[2].text, soup.find_all('p')[3].text):
            print x+"--"+y+"--"+z+"--"+e
            #Result for x is 'full name'
            #           y is 'occupation'
```

**Result

full name--occupation--0--a**

'full name' and 'occupation' works fine
'0' is the first character: it should be '000-345-678' 
'a' is first character: it should be 'alex@email.com'

But when I do it in different task, with only one URL. It works just fine

```
#This for 1 raw_input URL
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = raw_input("Link: ")
page = urllib2.urlopen(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

x= soup.h1.string
y= soup.find_all('p')[1].text
z= soup.find_all('p')[2].text
e= soup.find_all('p')[3].text

print x+"--"+y+"--"+z+"--"+e
```

Comment: Youre doing completely different things in your 1 URL version to what you're doing for a single URL in your multi version one. Why do you have the inner loop?

Comment: Is it? I did single URL first. Then I just loop multiple URL in text file. Getting the string/info pretty much the same thing.

Comment: The only loop you shouldve added was the `site` loop. Whats the other loop for, also why do you re-use `site` as a variable instead of using `page` like in the 1 URL example

Comment: first loop for site. Second for each item that I want in each site.

Comment: Okay, so why do you not have the loop for each item on the site in the single site version?

Comment: Yep. Silly me. Thank you. Nick A. It works now. I keep focusing on `.text`, thinking thats the problem. Thank you again.

Comment: If you've managed to solve your issue, you can write your own answer with what you did to fix it and accept your own answer, just make sure it's a full answer which could help future users, see [answer]

Comment: Do you know why it still got first character? I keep thinking the problem is with `.text` because it keep giving me wrong result of only the first character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Mistakenly have second loop*

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import itertools

with open('site_test.txt') as site_test:
sites = (line.strip() for line in site_test)
for site in sites:
    site = urllib2.urlopen(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site, "html.parser")

    x= soup.h1.string
    y= soup.find_all('p')[1].text
    z= soup.find_all('p')[2].text
    e= soup.find_all('p')[3].text

    print x+"--"+y+"--"+z+"--"+e
```